# Is there an quasi-elliptic fibration on a singular normal quartic surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces

Let $X$ be a singular normal quartic surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ over an algebraically closed field $k$ of even characteristic. Is there an quasi-elliptic fibration on $X$?

Comment: What do you mean by "quasi-elliptic fibration"?  A cone over a plane quartic curve is singular and normal, yet it admits no non-constant morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$ with connected fibers.

Comment: I mean by "quasi-elliptic fibration" a non-constant morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$ such that the generic fiber is a singular irreducible curve of arithmetic genus 1.

Comment: I am interested in the case when X has one elliptic singularity.

Comment: @SándorKovács. "If the general fiber is singular, then $X$ is not normal."  That is not correct.  If the function field of the base $\mathbb{P}^1$ is $k(t)$, and if the generic fiber is affine locally the zero scheme in $\mathbb{A}^2_{k(t)}$ of the polynomial $y^2-x^3-t$, then the fiber is normal, and even regular, even though it is not smooth over $k(t)$.

Comment: Jason, of course you are right. I got stuck thinking in char 0 even though the OP clearly said otherwise... At the same time you probably didn't write exactly what you meant....  :)

Comment: Perhaps I also miswrote.